# Bootstrap dropdown expanded at pageload

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap dropdown list. After the page has loaded, the menu is expanded. How can I fix this?

Here's a screenshot and code:

[image]

```
    <div class="col-lg-3">
       <div class="bs-component">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="dropdown open">
              <a id="ModelFilter" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="true">
                Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the class `open` from `<li>` element

```
<li class="dropdown"> ... </li>
```